# Using WolframAlpha with sympy to solve factorable quintics

Tags: python, math, sympy, wolframalpha

While trying to solve some factorable quintics with sympy, I noticed that it doesn't always find every solution, while wolframalpha does. Is there a way to use the softwares together, do something like:

```py
if no sympy_solutions
    solve.with.wolfram(...)
end if
```

Here is an example of a factorable quintic that sympy doesn't know how to solve: `16*x**5 - 20*x**3 + 5*x - sqrt(5)/4 - 1/4`.

Btw I have already tried the wolfram API, and it doesn't return exact roots, only approximations

Comment: You need to explain what "factorable" means (I expect that my understanding of the word is different from yours). Also you need to clarify what sort of form of answer you are hoping to get. SymPy has many different functions for computing roots of polynomials in different ways.

Comment: You'll need Python bindings for WolframAlpha. Something like [this](https://github.com/jaraco/wolframalpha) might help.

Comment: I tested the given expression with [WolframAlpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+16x**5+-+20x**3+%2B+5*x+-+sqrt%285%29%2F4+-+1%2F4) (online, free) and it neither didn't factorized the quintic nor found the roots. @Nicolas Campailla Could you add some details on your question? i.e. image of the results with Wolfram, listing the solution, sympy attempt, ...

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thank you for the answer! By factorable I mean that its roots (or solutions) can be found as a radical expression

Comment: WolframAlpha gives me the approximate roots, which I am also able to get from sympy using `nroots`.

Comment: Mathematica also does not give analytical roots, only numerical approximations (to this example).

Comment: @cards I tried using wolfram again and it doesn't give me the solutions anymore, possibly because of higher traffic and higher cumpute time? anyway, the solution is something like (1/10)*sqrt((20*(-1/4-(1/4)*sqrt(5)-(1/4)*sqrt(-10+2*sqrt(5))))*(-(3125/2048)*(-I*sqrt(5)*sqrt(2)+4*sqrt(5)*sqrt(sqrt(5)/(sqrt(5)-1))+(5*I)*sqrt(2)-8*sqrt(sqrt(5)/(sqrt(5)-1)))/((sqrt(5)-1)^2*sqrt(sqrt(5)/(sqrt(5)-1))))^(1/5)+50+(20*(-1/4-(1/4)*sqrt(5)+(1/4)*sqrt(-10+2*sqrt(5))))*(25/32+(1/2)*(3125/32768-(3125/32768)*sqrt(5))...(etc...)

Comment: I take that back, WolframAlpha does give me the exact form if requested. But the exact form has the imaginary number `i` while the approximate form is purely real, so I don't think the exact form is as simple as it should be. All the roots are real (for this problem).

Comment: @Woodford I have already tried that, and couldn't find a way for it to calculate radical roots of a polynomial, it gave me only approximate forms

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77928846/edit) your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: maybe working with [Galois groups](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/combinatorics/galois.html) you should be able to get information about the solvability, so no external dependency such as Wolfram... only maths

Comment: @jared This is pretty common, usually the i factores out when simplifying

Comment: @cards the polynomial is solvable, as it is derived from a formula for the cosine of (n*x). I'm not really sure how to tackle Galois, I am still a high school senior and a bit in over my head, but I am enjoying this process and what I'm learning from it!